# Flutter - AnimatedContainer not working to animate height

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a barcode widget that can be shown or hidden. I don't like the way it looks choppy without any animation so I tried making the height animated. I added `AnimatedContainers` everywhere I could think of and it still doesn't animate at all. Any ideas? The `BarcodeWidget` is from the `barcode_widget` package.

What it looks like now:
[image]

```
Widget shareBarcode() {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return shareExtended
        ? Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        shareExtended = false;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward_outlined),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                height: shareExtended ? height * 0.35 : 0,
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        height: shareExtended ? height * 0.35 : 0,
                        width: height * 0.3,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: const Color(0xFF6B6FAB),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Hero(
                                  tag: 'pfp-qr-${widget.uid}',
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7157A0),
                                    backgroundImage:
                                        NetworkImage(profile.profileInfo.pfpUrl),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(profile.profileInfo.displayName),
                              ],
                            ),
                            AnimatedContainer(
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              child: Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  BarcodeWidget(
                                    color: const Color(0xFFb1bbd8),
                                    barcode: Barcode.qrCode(
                                      errorCorrectLevel: BarcodeQRCorrectionLevel.high,
                                    ),
                                    data: widget.uid,
                                    width: shareExtended ? height * 0.25 : 0,
                                    height: shareExtended ? height * 0.25 : 0,
                                  ),
                                  AnimatedContainer(
                                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                    height: shareExtended ? 55 : 0,
                                    width: 55,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      boxShadow: const [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                            color: Colors.blueGrey, blurRadius: 5)
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height: 50,
                                      width: 50,
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                        child: Image.asset('assets/icon.png'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _shareBarcode();
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.ios_share,
                            color: Color(0xFF7157A0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        : Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    shareExtended = true;
                  });
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              )
            ],
          );
  }
```

Comment: Is the container expanding?  Share the gif how it works.

Comment: I just added a GIF of what it looks like right now with the code shown.

Comment: Try increasing the duration to some seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn’t change anything. I did try 2 seconds just to be sure but I have other animations that are 500 milliseconds and they work.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly skimmed through your code, and found that not all your `AnimatedContainer` have the `height` property? They need to have `height` property in order to animate their height. You can't just let it "automatically wrap their child" and hope it will work.

For example, this does **not** work:

```
AnimatedContainer(
  width: 300,
  // height property is missing
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: SizedBox(
    height: _condition ? 300 : 0, // the child size changes
  ),
)
```

But this **does** work:

```
AnimatedContainer(
  width: 300,
  height: _condition ? 300 : 0, // height property
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  color: Colors.blue,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Then try using any state management techniques as `BLoC, Get or Provider`. I think that `setState((){})` refreshes the page completely that might animation is no visible.

Comment: In Flutter, setState is just a way to notify the UI about changes like the height variable changing. You can see that in their own example https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/animated-container.

Answer (score 0):

What’s my solution as the OP? Find a workaround. I scrapped the whole drop down idea and instead I’m showing the widget as an overlay with a blur under it to make it the focus. It’s it what I wanted? No, but it works and I honestly like it better. Sometimes when you just can’t get something to work after days and nobody else can give a solution you just need to scrap the idea.